# Express.js fetch API with FormData object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following bit of code on a view

```
var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("hello", "world");
  fetch('/vision', {
    method: 'post',
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      hello: "world"
    })
  })
  .then(data => {
    debugger;
  })
```

and the action to handle

```
visionRouter.post("/", (req, res) => {
  vision.detectText(imageUrl, (err, text) => {
    res.send(text);
  })
});
```

The route is getting hit, but `req.body` doesn't exist.  How can you use fetch and FormData with express?

Comment: you need body-parser https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `body-parser` node module. Install it like this

```
npm install body-parser
```

Then in your code do this

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
visionRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Now your `req.body` will be able to access the JSON data you are sending